# Ingénieur en « automatique » ou en « automatisme » ?

Tags: informatique, professions

Je m'interroge sur le domaine qu'on appelle en anglais « automation ».

Est-ce qu'on dit : « Il est en *automatique*. » ou « Il est en *automatisme*. » ?

Et le domaine est celui d'*automatisme* ou d'*automatique* ?

Comment: bonjour, j'aimerais bien que vous m'aidiez a faire la différence l'automatique et l'automatisme et aussi bien si possible lequel des deux est le grand ensemble c'est a dire est ce dans l'automatisme qu'on trouve de l'automatique ou le contraire

Answer (score 5):

*Ingénieur automaticien* ou *en automatique*.  (Voir aussi la paire *mécanique*, *mécanisme*).

Answer (score -2):

[Automatique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatique) est l'équivalent de [Control engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_engineering). C'est un modèle de modélisation de systèmes physiques en équations mathématiques.

Vous utilisez donc plutôt [automatisme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatisme_%28organe%29), qui correspond à ce que vous appelez "automation". Le métier est [automaticien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaticien), comme l'a précisé **Un francophone**.

Comment: "Automation" et "Automatic control" désignent la même chose. Et le domaine d'étude est bien l'automatique, pas l'automatisme.

Comment: Effectivement, j'aurais dû dire Control engineering, je le corrige. Merci.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu _ingénieur en automatismes_ (oui, je mettrais _automatismes_ au pluriel si je devais employer cette expression) et je suis automaticien de formation.

Comment: On dit bien *mathématiques* et non *mathématisme* :)

Comment: J'ai un peu de mal à suivre. Quand je faisais des études en informatique industrielle, j'avais bien des cours d'automatismes (lié au travail d'automaticien) mais aussi de l'automatique. Cette matière consistait à représenter de manière mathématique différents systèmes physiques (thermique, fluides, électrique). On y étudiait notamment des choses comme l'asservissement et ce n'était pas lié à l'automatisme.